# R Shiny detect and delete local files after download

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Is it possible to detect when a user downloads a file after clicking a download button? I tried this but observeEvent cannot be used with output?:

```
observeEvent(output$downloadData2, {})
```

Download handler example:

ui.r:

```
downloadButton("downloadData2", "Download results")
```

server.r:

```
output$downloadData2 <- downloadHandler(
filename <- function() {
    paste("results.zip")
},      
content <- function(file) {
        workingdir = getwd()
        setwd("tmp/")
        file.copy(paste(direc,'.zip',sep=''), file)      
        setwd(workingdir)                
    },
    contentType = "application/zip"
)
```

Comment: You should use `input$downloadData2`

Comment: @warmoverflow the download handler doesn't register to input. Does not work.

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to do? User clicks a button, then downloads a file, then the file will be removed from server?

Comment: out of curiosity, have you figured this out? Just ran into the same problem. The issue is that we can't seem to be able to use observeEvent() on buttons that are created through the renderUI function server-side.

Comment: @BogdanRau I've come up with a better but different solution. Rather than deleting when a user downloads a file, I'm deleting all files in a temporary directory when the user exits the browser session. 

     `session$onSessionEnded(function() {`
  `unlink(sessiontemp, recursive = TRUE)`    
 `})`

Comment: excellent solution Jeff. I ended up doing the same, though mine had a useless second step. Thanks for your help!